# Converting input range to array in function

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have been learning VBA and thought I was getting the hang of it, but for some reason this basic task is eluding me. I am trying to create a function where I select an input region of numbers (really only one row or column), and then output the summation of the numbers in a cell. Here is my code:

```
Function CashFlow(CashArray As Excel.Range)

Dim cashflows() As Variant
cashflows = CashArray.Value

amount = CashArray.Rows.Count

dim y()
redim y(amount)
Sum = 0

For i = 1 To amount
    y(i) = cashflows(i)
    Sum = Sum + y(i)
Next i

CashFlow = Sum

End Function
```

Despite me knowing how to do essentially this in a subroutine, the fact that I'm getting my data from the function's input is throwing me off. How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: Range (with more than one cell) is 2 dimensional array.

Comment: What that means is: `y(i) = cashflows(i,1)` for vertical and `y(i) = cashflows(1,i)` for horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize the above comments, please give the following code a try:

```
Option Explicit

Function CashFlow(CashArray As Excel.Range)

Dim sum As Double
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim cashflows() As Variant

cashflows = CashArray.Value
sum = 0

For y = LBound(cashflows, 1) To UBound(cashflows, 1)
    For x = LBound(cashflows, 2) To UBound(cashflows, 2)
        sum = sum + cashflows(y, x)
    Next x
Next y

CashFlow = sum

End Function
```

Note, that this code summarizes all cells in the given range (even if there are multiple rows *and* columns in that range). Basically, the range is stored in the array `cashflows`. As mentioned in the comments, this will yield a two-dimensional array. The function `LBound(cashflows)` will give you the **L**ower **Bound**ary of that array.

By specifying `LBound(cashflows, 1)` I am specifically asking for the lower boundary of the first dimension (in this case the rows). `UBound` returns the **U**pper **Bound**ary of that array for the specified dimension. Similarily `UBound(cashflows, 2)` returns the last column (second dimension) of the given array.

<sub>Remark: I am always using `LBound()` and `UBound()` in my code instead of starting with `0` or `1` to avoid coding errors. Some people prefer `Option Base 0` and some prefer `Option Base 1`. While neither will have an impact on the above (as ranges always yield an array starting with `1`) it is just good coding practice to prevent bugs in the future.</sub>

Comment: So, what you (and the comments as well) taught me is that ranges can be created automatically and intuitively, but they have multiple dimensions that must be specified (even if it's just 1 column or 1 row for one of the dims.). Thank you for this insight, and the additional tips on UBound and LBound!

P.S. I found that declaring your inputs "as excel.range" is not necessary in the first place, fyi.